# Reading more than 500MB data from amazon s3 and storing in RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have an RDS PostgreSQL instance. I have my own s3. In my project I will upload some excel files in s3. When a file falls on s3 i need to read the excel file and store it into the DB.

I created a lambda function using java and added trigger to the lambda function. When a file falls on s3 my lambda function invokes automatically and reading the file and saving it into the db.

But the probelm is when in my case my file is more than 100MB at a time. The lambda works only for 5 minutes.

So i could not save my file completely tho the DB. I heard kinesis in AWS. As a newbie to the AWS I don't know how to use it? Is there any who can help me to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Kinesis is probably not the solution to your problem.

The limiting factor in your case is the execution time limit of the Lambda function, which tops at 5 minutes.

In order to extend that execution time, what I would do is use a SQS queue and a EC2 instance. When a file falls in your S3 bucket, you configure your bucket to publish events to a SQS queue. See examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) on how to do that.

The EC2 instance periodically polls the SQS queue for new events. When a new event is put in the queue, the EC2 instance retrieves the event, and copies the S3 file's data into your DB.

EDIT: Lambda now stops at 15 minutes of execution instead of 5

Comment: Hi @spg. I found one more solution as u suggested. Thanks!!! But you know I used kinesis service which includes lambda works for me. Actually i have to insert 9 lakh record at a time. But currently i have a file with 15MB. By using kinesis it works fine now. Now I am confused about that the best method is your suggestion? or did I fail while I am inserting 8lakh record with my current code?

Comment: AWS has increased limits on Lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html